# Typescript primitive string has no methods

Tags: typescript

I have read string primitive type in Typescript has no methods. It is just a value.
If we need methods (like toLowerCase() for example), we need to work with String type.

Here is what i've tried:

```
let s = "Hello";
console.log(typeof(s));   // string
s = s.toLowerCase();
```

I don't understand: I have created a string variable and i was able to call toLowerCase method on it... Can you explain me why this is possible ?

And what's the value-add of String ?

Thanks

Comment: but what is wrong in strings having methods?

Comment: The `string` type does indeed have all the methods of `String` in TypeScript.  In *JavaScript*, a primitive `string` doesn't "have" methods, but it will become auto-wrapped in a `String` object if you treat it like it does. That means, pragmatically, `string`s in JavaScript also have methods.  So `String` is the wrapper interface for `string` primitives, and `string` is essentially a subtype of `String`. (more)

Comment: (continued)The `String` interface is what gets updated when strings get new methods in TS, so it needs to exist. There is almost no "value-add" for `String` when it comes to *users*; [just use `string`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer or find a dupe target; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

[because it’s a type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/86a16636cac9599c8752f8588f4b9518860b47ff/src/lib/es2020.string.d.ts#L2)

When in doubt, check the source code of TypeScript, it’s all open source and free to view.